# Есть ли аналог параметра --mode=universal для flutter?

Tags: flutter, android-bundle

Параметр --mode=universal не работает не работает вместе с командой flutter build appbundle. Аргумент --mode=universal предназначен для bundletool, есть ли для flutter build аналог этого аргумента? Или есть другой способ получить универсальный flutter .apk в bundle .aab?

Comment: Это можно сделать отдельно через [bundletool](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool): `bundletool build-apks --bundle=my_app.aab --output=my_app.apks --mode=universal`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Он правильный, но я не могу пометить его как верный, потому что вы написали его в комментарии, можете переписать его как ответ и я помечу его как истинный?

Comment: добавил в ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это можно сделать отдельно через [bundletool](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool): `bundletool build-apks --bundle=my_app.aab --output=my_app.apks --mode=universal`